# mysql query listener

Tags: sql, mysql

Do you know a tool that i will be able to see what queries where run against the database .

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built in [MySql Query Profiler](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html).

> The new profiler became available in the 5.0.37 version of the MySQL Community Server

And:

> To begin profiling one or more SQL queries, simply issue the following command:
>
> mysql> set profiling=1;
>
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>
> Two things happen once you issue this command. First, any query you issue from this point on will be traced by the server with various performance diagnostics being created and attached to each distinct query. Second, a memory table named profiling is created in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database for your particular session (not viewable by any other MySQL session) that stores all the SQL diagnostic results. This table remains persistent until you disconnect from MySQL at which point it is destroyed.